# Console interface tutorials and tips (pdcurses)

Tags: console, ncurses, curses, pdcurses

I'm looking for tutorials on using PDCurses library. Unfortunately there is text only documentation, which is more like function reference. Are pdcurses similar enough to ncurses to use ncurses tutorials??? Any tips for making console UI's ???

PS. PDCurses - mingw32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [blog entry](http://cymonsgames.com/learning-curses-by-example/) isn't anything I'd call a tutorial but it looks like it might be an interesting starting point. It is featuring a (very, very basic) [video tutorial](http://cymonsgames.com/getting-started/) on YouTube as well.

Comment: The link to blog entry should be corrected to http://cymonsgames.com/learning-curses-by-example/

Answer (score 6):

You can always use [this tutorial for Ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/), and change the #include from ncurses.h to curses.h in order to use pdcurses.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know PDcurses itself but with such a name I'd expect it to be curses-compatible.  Have you checked APIs between the two?

Comment: -1 It just does not answer the question. As for 2015, you can find some information on compatibility of both libraries in [PDCurses User's Guide] (http://wmcbrine.com/pdcurses/doc/PDCurses.txt) and [NCURSES FAQ](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html).